# Pin program to start menu with always elevated privileges windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I want to pin a program to the windows 10 start menu, and I want them to always run with elevated privileges. This is so I don't always have to remember to press "run as administrator". This is easy to accomplish if you "pin to taskbar", but I have found no way to do it on the start menu.

Is this possible with the default windows 10 menu?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

1. Press windows key and enter "powershell", among the results select a
   link to powershell, rightclick and select "Open file location".
   You'll get to the folder where the shortcuts to the powershell are.
2. Copy the shortcut to powershell to that same folder. The key point
   is to name it in such way that it would appear first among shortcuts
   in that folder when sorting by name ascending (that's really
   critical :). I gave it a name "PS Elevated".
3. Go to properties of that new shortcut, "Shortcut" tab -> Advanced -> set "Run as administrator" checkbox and apply.
4. Rightclick new shortcut and select "Pin to Start"

Done.

However, it would always ask your permission to start as administrator anyways. And that new shortcut would be default match when searching for powershell.

Answer (score 0):

i am not using windows 10 yet but likely it gonna be the same as previous windows, you can make a program run by default with administrator privileges by doing this steps :

> right click on exe file (original not shortcut) > properties >
>   compatibility tab > check run "this program as an administrator" > ok

then where ever you call the program it will run as an administrator

Comment: Two problems with this. 1: not all programs has a compatibiliy tab, devenv and cmd beeing two of them. 2: I want the shortcut elevated, not every instanse of the program

Comment: In any case, while this was the behavior in previous versions, this doesn't work with Windows 10 any more.